# Problem calling the prediction endpoint uploading an image using rest sharp for the Microsoft custom vision API cognitive service

Tags: c#, restsharp, microsoft-custom-vision

I am trying to upload an image to the Microsoft custom vision API prediction endpoint using Restsharp, I am trying to use the AddFile method but I am getting a BadRequest as the result, here is the code I am using

```
public IRestResponse<PredictionResponse> Predict(string imageFileName)
    {
        var file = new FileInfo(imageFileName);
        var serviceUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api.custom-vision.prediction.url.file"];
        var serviceKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api.custom-vision.key"];
        var client = new RestClient(serviceUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        request.AddHeader("Prediction-Key", serviceKey);
        request.AddFile(file.Name, file.FullName);
        var response = client.Execute<PredictionResponse>(request);
        return response;
    }
```

When I execute the method I am getting the following response back from the service

```
{
  "code": "BadRequestImageFormat",
  "message": "Bad Request Image Format, Uri: 1062fe0480714281abe2daf17beb3ac5"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking for ways in the restsharp documentation to properly upload a file, I came to the solution that it needs to be passed as parameter with an array of bytes with the parameter type of *ParameterType.RequestBody*

Here is the example of the method that actually works

```
public IRestResponse<PredictionResponse> Predict(string imageFileName)
        {
            var file = new FileInfo(imageFileName);
            var serviceUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api.custom-vision.prediction.url.file"];
            var serviceKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api.custom-vision.key"];
            var client = new RestClient(serviceUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            request.AddHeader("Prediction-Key", serviceKey);
            request.AddParameter("content", File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName), ParameterType.RequestBody);
            var response = client.Execute<PredictionResponse>(request);
            return response;
        }
```